# wso2 quickfixj fix.4.2 message from broker

Tags: wso2, fix-protocol, apache-synapse, quickfixj

Good morning everyone,

I have problem when waiting for fix message from my broker to my wso2.
i have setup my proxy for got fix message from them like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="FIXtoSOAP" startOnLoad="true" transports="fix" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <log level="full" />
      <log level="full" />
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <log level="full" />
    </outSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.fix.AcceptorConfigURL">
    file:/home/ec2-user/xxxx_server_new/FIXQUoteAcceptor2.cfg
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.fix.AcceptorMessageStore">file</parameter>
</proxy>
```

but in my console i cannot see their message in my console. by the way i am new for use FIX transport using wso2.

Comment: Please don't add information to your question by posting comments as it's virtually unreadable. Click 'edit' and add it, with the correct formatting, to your question.

Comment: Formatted set XML as the source type and formatted it.

Comment: @Chris i also have add  <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/> but my fix message not convert as xml as i expected. can you help me how the step by step for it

Comment: my question is how to this message <20200313-10:28:18, FIX.4.2:mycomp->mybroker, incoming> (8=FIX.4.29=015135=X34=249=mybroker152=20200313-10:28:18.60656=mycomp262=VT_021268=01279=055=EUR/USD269=1278=1073741875270=1.11699271=0200000010=242) become soap xml format. please help me for fix it

Comment: did you fix this? @yuyukungkung